# express and compression, can't find what I make wrong :-(

Tags: node.js, express, curl, http-compression

I can't find why I can't compress my content.
I tried many way but when I check with curl ( curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://localhost:8080/free.html ) on a static page or on basic local content ( / ) I can't find any way to compress my content

What did I made wrong ?
Here is my code :

```js
var express = require('express');
var compression =   require('compression');
var morgan =        require('morgan');
var favicon =       require('serve-favicon');

var app =           express();

app.use(compression({
    filter: function () { return true; }
}));
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Vous êtes à l\'accueil');
});
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.send(404);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

thanks

Gregoire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't figured out *why* yet, but it appears that if the threshold isn't set low enough, it won't encode it. Here's an example:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var compression = require('compression')

app.use(compression({ threshold: 6 }))
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('done')
})

var server = app.listen(8080)
```

The docs state that `6` is the default. When I test this:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://localhost:8080
```

The Content-Encoding header is not set. When I set it to a threshold 4 or lower, it then responds with encoded content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip   // <——————————
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 20:23:24 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

K??K??-⏎
```

Comment: You rock ! It's exactly the point, adding the threshold was the point ! Thank you very much !